# EPS is not shown up

Tags: graphics

I am trying to use a simple template for latex and include some images on it. The import I have in the beginning are:

```
\documentclass[dvips,11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
```

while the code for showing the images:

```
\begin{figure}[thb]
\begin{center}
 \includegraphics[width=2.84in]{sample.eps}   

{\small Text below figure}         
\end{center}
\caption{{\small Caption for Figure.}}
\end{figure}
```

while the sample.eps is in the same folder with .tex file I am able to compile the .tex file, however, I cannot see the image only the caption. What is the issue? The whole file [can be found here](https://textuploader.com/dnudx).

Comment: Are you sure that there is nothing wrong with the .eps file?

Comment: Yes I can see the image outside of tex (from overleaf viewer).

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. Note that it is better to add a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to your question: full code, so in your case you would need to add `\begin{document}` etc.

Comment: Make this into a single mwe and make sure that is what you test. Also you should not be centering using the center env (excessive vertical space), or adding formatting into the caption like that (learn to configure the caption using the caption package)

Comment: Additionally there is no need to add the dvips option to graphicx it will detect it automatically, are you compiling using pdflatex or latex+dvips+ps2pdf (or similar). Are you getting any warnings or errors.

Comment: This is a template code for a submission. It was by default there. I am using overleaf default compile.

Comment: If you leave out the `dvips` twice (in `\documentclass[dvips,11pt,twoside]{article}` and in `\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}`), it works.

Comment: And now you know why we are suspicious of most templates.

Answer (score 2):

If you leave out the dvips twice:

- in `\documentclass[dvips,11pt,twoside]{article}`
- in `\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx})`

it works.